# Angular cli integrating 3rd party library

Tags: angular, gulp, angular-cli

> I have a project built with @angular/cli and a 3rd party library
>   created by me called ng2-tools. When I install this library and run it
>   using @angular cli I get this error

```
ERROR in Ng2ToolsModule is not an NgModule
```

> But if I erase one module and add it back the error disappears and the
>   applicatin  runs fine. What I cannot do is to build the application
>   because of the same error. Here is the link for [ng2-tools](https://github.com/nicolae536/ng2Tools)
>   library, the master branch has the published code, [this](https://github.com/nicolae536/nicolae536.github.io) is the application built with
>   angular/cli which throws the error on develop branch is the source code. Should I publish more info for npm
>   to not get this error? How is a library bundled in for angular 2 ? I'm using 
>   gulp for building the library, so I can get each file compiled separately.
>   This is the source code from app.module

```
import { MaterialModule } from '@angular/material';
import { CommonModule } from '@angular/common';
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { FormsModule } from '@angular/forms';
import { HttpModule } from '@angular/http';
import { RouterModule } from '@angular/router';
import { Ng2TableModule } from 'ng2-table/ng2-table';

import {  Ng2ToolsModule } from 'ng2-tools/module';

import { APP_ROUTES } from './app.routes';
import { APP_COMPONENTS } from './app-components';
import { AppComponent } from './app.component';

@NgModule({
    declarations: [
        AppComponent,
        ...APP_COMPONENTS
    ],
    imports: [
        Ng2TableModule,
        CommonModule,
        FormsModule,
        BrowserModule,
        MaterialModule,
        HttpModule,
        Ng2ToolsModule,
        RouterModule.forRoot(APP_ROUTES)
    ],
    bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule {
}
```

> And this is the code for Ng2ToolsModule

```
import { NgModule } from "@angular/core";

import { AutocompleteModule, GenericFormModule } from './components/index';
import { DirectivesModule } from "./directives/directives.module";
import { CORE_SERVICES } from "./services/index";

@NgModule({
    imports: [AutocompleteModule, GenericFormModule, DirectivesModule],
    exports: [AutocompleteModule, GenericFormModule, DirectivesModule],
    providers: [CORE_SERVICES]
})
export class Ng2ToolsModule {
}
```

Comment: Can you post sourcecode from App module?

Comment: Yes I updated the question

Comment: And as I understand Ng2ToolsModule is your module right?

Comment: Yes,  what is odd is if I erase any other module from the app module let the cli to compile the application and the add the module again the cli compiles the application right and the application works

Comment: can you share code of that module?

Comment: I just added it

Comment: I will report a cli bug with this.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that my build system does not build the bundle to be aot compatible, I manage to build a library for npm and angular >= 2 using the build config from @ngrx/store  right now I'm writing a form component after I move that to a separate repo I will post a link to the repository.

Here is my library if you want to give it a try. [library built using ngrx/store config](https://github.com/nicolae536/ng-lock-system)

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that my build system does not build the bundle to be aot compatible, I manage to build a library for npm and angular >= 2 using the build config from @ngrx/store right now I'm writing a form component after I move that to a separate repo I will post a link to the repository.

Here is my library if you want to give it a try.

[library built using ngrx/store build config](https://github.com/nicolae536/ng-lock-system)